# Magento abandoned cart for guest/unconfirmed users

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, magento-1.5

In Magento abandoned cart only works for verified registered users. Is there a way to capture it for guest and unconfirmed users **programmaticaly**?

Also is there a way to email alert for the same?

Please tell me atleast where should I start on this. I found on a forum that with below SQL you can get all the abandoned carts, but I found some of them missing from there as well.

```
SELECT entity_id, customer_firstname, customer_email, items_count, grand_total, created_at
FROM sales_flat_quote
WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT quote_item_id AS quote_id FROM sales_flat_order_item) 
AND items_count >0
AND customer_email IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY `sales_flat_quote`.`created_at` DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

I use a third party system for doing something like this. They cost but can be a valuable tool, especially if you have impulsive buy items. As the user is not logged in on the site, Magento can only store their basket as a quote using their session, so you are not able to get any details about the customer or the abandoned cart other than the contents of it.

If you are only interested in the items added to peoples abandoned baskets you can create custom SQL looking at the two tables you have identified in your example. Magento creates a quote for every cart which gets converted into an order when the customer purchases so the sales_quotes are table are where you need to start.

Regarding third party services, they normally involve having listeners on text boxes on the site such as email text box, name etc which post data using ajax when the field is modified. Good for capturing data during guest checkout if you have it enabled and the customer fails to finalize purchase. They do the same for add to cart buttons and start to build up a custom profile of the customer and the items in their cart as they use the site.

When somebody orders you then call another ajax request which tells the third party the customer has purchased, and those that it does not get this final request from is what it classifies as an abandoned cart. Most of these systems will email the customer after a set amount of time and days which you can define and you can normally send many emails at different time periods. You can normally also view all the abandoned carts and customer data that has been collected.

Magento's built in abandoned cart is ok for basic use but I wouldn't rely upon it. AFAIK it has no way of triggering emails for abandoned carts. E-Mail retargeting as described above can be very effective at re-capturing abandoned sales.

Have a look at somebody like exacttarget or search for magento email abandoned cart modules as I believe there are a few around that will plug and play with magento.

Comment: Thanks Ashly for your reply. But If I can understand "How abandoned cart works" and where can I find code for same in magento then I can either customize it or can create a new module. Or even if I get the sql idea then I can write a custom query in cron job to send reminder mail. I don't feel that for this small functionality I should buy third party module.

Answer (score 2):

I was having same issue and able to solve it into magento 1.9.2 by following method:

**Step-1:**

Copy **Collection.php** file from
**app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Quote/**

to

**app/code/local/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Quote/**

**Step-2:**

replace following code from line no: 194

```
$customerName = $adapter->getConcatSql(array('cust_fname.value', 'cust_mname.value', 'cust_lname.value',), ' ');
    $this->getSelect()
        ->joinInner(
            array('cust_email' => $attrEmailTableName),
            'cust_email.entity_id = main_table.customer_id',
            array('email' => 'cust_email.email')
        )
        ->joinInner(
            array('cust_fname' => $attrFirstnameTableName),
            implode(' AND ', array(
                'cust_fname.entity_id = main_table.customer_id',
                $adapter->quoteInto('cust_fname.attribute_id = ?', (int) $attrFirstnameId),
            )),
            array('firstname' => 'cust_fname.value')
        )
        ->joinInner(
            array('cust_mname' => $attrMiddlenameTableName),
            implode(' AND ', array(
                'cust_mname.entity_id = main_table.customer_id',
                $adapter->quoteInto('cust_mname.attribute_id = ?', (int) $attrMiddlenameId),
            )),
            array('middlename' => 'cust_mname.value')
        )
        ->joinInner(
            array('cust_lname' => $attrLastnameTableName),
            implode(' AND ', array(
                'cust_lname.entity_id = main_table.customer_id',
                 $adapter->quoteInto('cust_lname.attribute_id = ?', (int) $attrLastnameId)
            )),
            array(
                'lastname'      => 'cust_lname.value',
                'customer_name' => $customerName
            )
        );

    $this->_joinedFields['customer_name'] = $customerName;
    $this->_joinedFields['email']         = 'cust_email.email';
```

with

```
        $customerName = $adapter->getConcatSql(array('main_table.customer_firstname', 'main_table.customer_middlename', 'main_table.customer_lastname',), ' ');
    $this->getSelect()
            ->columns(
                     array(
                         'email' => new Zend_Db_Expr('main_table.customer_email'), 
                         'firstname'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('main_table.customer_firstname'),
                         'middlename' => new Zend_Db_Expr('main_table.customer_middlename'),
                         'lastname'   => new Zend_Db_Expr('main_table.customer_lastname'),
                         'customer_name' => $customerName
                        )
            )
            ->where('main_table.customer_email IS NOT NULL');


    $this->_joinedFields['customer_name'] = $customerName;
    $this->_joinedFields['email']         = 'main_table.customer_email';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load cart for a guest if you know quote id. Try the following code:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByIdWithoutStore($quoteId);
if ($quote) {
                      Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setQuoteId($quoteId);
                    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->setQuote($quote);                      
}
```